# JNLP File with Eclipse

Tags: swing, java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have done A *lot* of researching, but I can't seem to figure out how to make a JNLP file with Eclipse. I know some XML, and what I am trying to do is launch a (Java) Swing program from the Desktop as a Desktop application and online. can someone please help me?

Comment: Please do visit [**this link**](https://gagandeepbali.uk.to/svn/myrepository/tables/), I had created one JNLP a long time back, though I had kept the files here, that might can give you some idea about the content of the JNLP files and this document for how to [**SIGN JAR FILES**](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/downloads/signJARfiles.txt). Hopefully this might can help you somewhat. **USERNAME : guest PASSWORD : guest**  . Sorry, about the fact, that I forgot to place the actual link before :-) **Look inside bin folder**.

Comment: One more valuable link for you : [**Deploying Software with JNLP and Java Web Start**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-135962.html)

Comment: See also [*Java Web Start*](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: If you can run an Ant based build file in Eclipse, see [these examples](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to launch Swing applet application from Eclipse.

You can either create launch file, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.javaApplet">
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/some.zip"/>
</listAttribute>
<mapAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.preferred_launchers">
<mapEntry key="[debug]" value="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.javaApplet"/>
<mapEntry key="[run]" value="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.javaApplet"/>
</mapAttribute>
<intAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_HEIGHT" value="905"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_NAME" value=""/>
<mapAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_PARAMETERS">
<mapEntry key="someEntry" value="5131"/>
</mapAttribute>
<intAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_WIDTH" value="1265"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH">
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" value="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="com.some.YourApplet"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

This option is good for testing swing application locally.

Or, if you still want to use jnlp, it is also possible to have jnlp with proper codebase, the same that you have in your jar.

If you have errors while launching jnlp locally,  please post it.